# When installing the AMD GPU driver, I received an error message

Tags: amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

When I try to install the AMD GPU driver I see the below error message before finish installing.

My GPU is rx570 4GB and my system is ubuntu 20.04.2LTS

[image]

Comment: Did you search for a possible cause/solution? 
Please post specifically what you found.

Comment: `uname -a` please add this to  your question. My suspicion it can not be build against your kernel.

Comment: AMD graphics cards have kernel level drivers and are natively supported by Linux/Ubuntu. For most tasks, you dont need to install drivers

Comment: after reboot, I can not see desktop and it is blocked amdgpu module.

Comment: my kernal    Linux SALOMY-PC 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I want to install driver for gaming and mining

Comment: You don't need the proprietary overlay for neither. Save yourself the trouble of this installation and just use the system with the included official driver.

Comment: @ ChanganAuto I can not see my GPU in nano miner I think I need to install driver